# Show netmask using ip tool

Tags: ip, network-interface

I would like to know how to get the mask of a network interface.
With `ifconfig` it is very simple, but I have to use the `ip` tool, and `ip addr show` is not showing me what I want.

Here is an example output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Also, what is that brd field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subnet mask in CIDR notation (for example /8) represents the bits used for the subnet mask.

The 'old' way of 255.255.255.0 shows you 4 bytes of 8 bits each. A typical subnet mask for the loopback address 127.0.0.1 is 255.0.0.0. This means that one byte (8 bits) is fully used as the subnet mask. It is written as the /8 in 127.0.0.1/8.

Another often used subnet is 192.168.0.0. The default subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. From this you can read that 3 bytes consisting of 8 bits each is used for the subnet mask. Those 3 bytes x 8 bits equals to 24. Such a network is written as 192.168.0.0/24. If you are presented with an address like 192.168.0.1/24 you know that 24 bits are used for the subnetmask.

Comment: Is it possible to have a netmask that is not multiple of 8?

Comment: yes; that's the main benefit to CIDR networks

Comment: see, for example, http://www.subnetmask.info/

Answer (score 5):

1. The `/8` in `127.0.0.1/8` is the netmask.
2. `brd` is short for "broadcast". [online man page for ip](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)

Bonus tip - use `ip -o addr show` to get one-line output that's slightly easier to extract data from.

Comment: I'm not used to this notation, I was expecting something like 255.255.255.0. How can I translate one into the other?

Comment: apt-get install ipcalc ; try "ipcalc 127.0.0.1/8"

Comment: more specifically, `ipcalc -m 127.0.0.1/8`

Comment: `netmask` is a good tool for this too.  `apt-get install netmask`.  homepage at https://github.com/talby-/netmask

Comment: @Kira I agree. I don't see why the `ip` command doesn't just show the subnet mask like `ifconfig` does. E.g: /24 = 255.255.255.0